# Convert /reshape a dataset from 'wide to long' format and convert the time column into time format for time-series analysis

Tags: python, pandas, plot, time-series

I have a dataset with 7 columns - `level`,`Time_30`,`Time_60`,`Time_90`,`Time_120`,`Time_150` and `Time_180`

My main goal is to do a time-series anomaly detection using cell count in a 30-minute interval.

I want to do the following data preparation steps:

(I) melt/reshape the `df` into the appropriate time-series format (from wide to long)- consolidate the columns `time_30`, `time_60` ,....., `time_180` into one column `time` with 6 levels (`30`,`60`,.....,`180`)

(II) since the result from (I) comes out as `30,60,.....180`, I want to set the `time` column as the appropriate time or date format for time-series (something like this '%H:%M:%S')

(III) use a for-loop to plot the time-series plot for each level - `A`, `B`,...., `F`) for comparison purposes.

(IV) Anomaly detection

```
# generate/import dataset
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'level':[A,B,C,D,E,F], 
       'Time_30':[1993.05,1999.45, 2001.11, 2007.39, 2219.77],
       'Time_60':[2123.15,2299.59, 2339.19, 2443.37, 2553.15],
       'Time_90':[2323.56,2495.99,2499.13, 2548.71, 2656.0],
       'Time_120':[2355.52,2491.19,2519.92,2611.81, 2753.11],
       'Time_150':[2425.31,2599.51, 2539.9, 2713.77, 2893.58],
       'Time_180':[2443.35,2609.92, 2632.49, 2774.03, 2901.25]} )
```

Desired outcome

```
# first series
level, time, count
A, 30, 1993.05
B, 60, 2123.15
C, 90, 2323.56
D, 120, 2355.52
E, 150, 2425.31
F, 180, 2443.35 

# 2nd series 
level,time,count 
A,30,1999.45
B,60,2299.59
C,90,2495.99
D,120,2491.19
E,150,2599.51
F,180,2609.92

.
.
.
.
# up until the last series
```

See below for my attempt

```
# (I)
df1 = pd.melt(df,id_vars = ['level'],var_name = 'time',value_name = 'count') #

# (II)

df1['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['time'],format= '%H:%M:%S' ).dt.time

OR

df1['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df1['time'], unit='m')


# (III)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.plot(df1)
for timex in range(30,180):
    plt.axvline(datetime(timex,1,1), color='k', linestyle='--', alpha=0.3)

# Perform STL Decomp
stl = STL(df1)
result = stl.fit()

seasonal, trend, resid = result.seasonal, result.trend, result.resid

plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))

plt.subplot(4,1,1)
plt.plot(df1)
plt.title('Original Series', fontsize=16)

plt.subplot(4,1,2)
plt.plot(trend)
plt.title('Trend', fontsize=16)

plt.subplot(4,1,3)
plt.plot(seasonal)
plt.title('Seasonal', fontsize=16)

plt.subplot(4,1,4)
plt.plot(resid)
plt.title('Residual', fontsize=16)

plt.tight_layout()

estimated = trend + seasonal
plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
plt.plot(df1)
plt.plot(estimated)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
plt.plot(resid)

# Anomaly detection 

resid_mu = resid.mean()
resid_dev = resid.std()

lower = resid_mu - 3*resid_dev
upper = resid_mu + 3*resid_dev

anomalies = df1[(resid < lower) | (resid > upper)] # returns the datapoints with the anomalies
anomalies


plt.plot(df1)
for timex in range(30,180):
    plt.axvline(datetime(timex,1,1), color='k', linestyle='--', alpha=0.6)
    
plt.scatter(anomalies.index, anomalies.count, color='r', marker='D')
```

Please note:  if you can only attempt I and/or II that would be much appreciated.

Comment: There seem to be some errors above. In your sample dataframe, the `A, B, C...` needs to be `'A','B','C',...`, and you have six items in the `level` column, but only 5 in the others. Second, should your desired result for the first series actually have A-F, or should those all be A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few small edits to your sample dataframe based on my comment above:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'level':['A','B','C','D','E'], 
       'Time_30':[1993.05,1999.45, 2001.11, 2007.39, 2219.77],
       'Time_60':[2123.15,2299.59, 2339.19, 2443.37, 2553.15],
       'Time_90':[2323.56,2495.99,2499.13, 2548.71, 2656.0],
       'Time_120':[2355.52,2491.19,2519.92,2611.81, 2753.11],
       'Time_150':[2425.31,2599.51, 2539.9, 2713.77, 2893.58],
       'Time_180':[2443.35,2609.92, 2632.49, 2774.03, 2901.25]} )
```

First, manipulate the `Time_*` column names to be integer values:

```
timecols = [int(c.replace("Time_","")) for c in df.columns if c != 'level']
df.columns = ['level'] + timecols
```

After that you can `pd.melt()` like you were thinking, yielding a datarame with all those "series" you mentioned above concatenated together:

```
df1 = df.melt(id_vars=['level'], value_vars=timecols, var_name='time', value_name='count').sort_values(['level','time']).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df1.head(10))
  level time    count
0     A   30  1993.05
1     A   60  2123.15
2     A   90  2323.56
3     A  120  2355.52
4     A  150  2425.31
5     A  180  2443.35
6     B   30  1999.45
7     B   60  2299.59
8     B   90  2495.99
9     B  120  2491.19
```

If you want to loop over the `level`s, select them with:

```
for level in df1['level'].unique():
    tmp = df1[df1['level']==level]
```

or

```
for level in df1['level'].unique():
    tmp = df1[df1['level']==level].copy()
```

...if you intend to modify/add data to the tmp dataframe.

As for making timestamps, you *could* do:

```
df1['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df1['time'], unit='min')
```

...like you were attempting, but it depends on how you're using it. If you just want strings that look like "00:30:00", etc, you can try something like:

```
df1['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df1['time'], unit='min').apply(lambda x:str(x)[-8:])
```

Anyway, hope that gets you on track for what you need.

Comment: `@Rick M`  Thanks a lot.